# What's the meaning of "any" in "python3:any (>= 3.5)" in a Debian `control` file?

Tags: debian-packaging

In `meson`'s `debian/control` file, I see its `Build-Depends` is as follows (see the last line):

```
Source: meson
Maintainer: Jussi Pakkanen <jpakkane@gmail.com>
Section: devel
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 4.5.0
Homepage: https://mesonbuild.com
X-Python3-Version: >= 3.7
Rules-Requires-Root: no
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 12),
  python3:any (>= 3.5),
  ... ...
```

**What is the meaning of "any" in "python3:any (>= 3.5)"?**

I found [the related part of the source code here](https://git.dpkg.org/cgit/dpkg/dpkg.git/tree/scripts/Dpkg/Deps/Simple.pm#n174) (and hopefully I found the right code):

```
return if not $dep =~
       m{^\s*                           # skip leading whitespace
          ($pkgname_re)                 # package name
          (?:                           # start of optional part
            :                           # colon for architecture
            ([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)  # architecture name
          )?                            # end of optional part
```

The code comment says the ":any" part specifies the architecture.

However, after reading the following chapters in *Debian Policy Manual v4.5.0.2*:

- [1] [5. Control files and their fields](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html)
- [2] [7. Declaring relationships between packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html)

[2] does talk about the bracket syntax (e.g., "hurd-dev [hurd-i386]") that specifies the architectures that the package should be installed. **I haven't found the text that mentions this colon syntax.**

So my previous question can be further divided into:

1. Am I correct that the "any" part specifies the architecture?
2. If "any" specifies the architecture, what's the difference between the colon syntax (e.g., "python3:any") and the bracket syntax (e.g., "hurd-dev [hurd-i386]")?
3. Why is the colon syntax needed if we already have the bracket syntax?
4. **Most importantly**, could someone point me to the related documentation for this colon syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right terms first so they lead to the right docs. First of all, such fields as **Build-Depends** are called [*relationship fields*](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html). And there I could find that

> Relationships may be restricted to a certain set of architectures.
> This is indicated in brackets after each individual package name and
> the optional version specification. The brackets enclose a non-empty
> list of *Debian architecture names* in the format described in
> *Architecture specification strings*, separated by whitespace.

So, then *Architecture specification strings* is what we are looking for. From [this](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s-arch-spec) we  can deduce that these are defined by **dpkg-architecture**. And from [its manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dpkg-dev/dpkg-architecture.1.en.html), *architecture name* is either

> The **Debian architecture string**, which specifies
> the binary tree in the FTP archive. Examples: i386, sparc, hurd-i386.

or

> An **architecture wildcard** is a special
> architecture string that will match any real architecture being part
> of it. The general form is -. Examples: linux-any,
> any-i386, hurd-any.

[Here is additional explanation](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-architecture):

> Specifying only **any** indicates that the source package isn’t dependent
> on any particular architecture and should compile fine on any one. The
> produced binary package(s) will be specific to whatever the current
> build architecture is.

,BTW contrary to **all** which

> indicates that the source package will only build
> architecture-independent packages

Comment: Aha! Somehow I didn't see the "The brackets enclose a non-empty list of Debian architecture names"... That's what I was trying to find. Thanks for that and the rest of the information!